# How to Disable YouTube Mix Recommendations?

Tags: youtube

YouTube sometimes recommends me playlists called "Mix - Some music video" where the "Some music video" part is the name of a video that I have watched previously. These mix recommendations typically have thumbnail image that looks like the thumbnail of the original video. I sometimes click on them because I wish to revisit the video I already watched. However, I almost never have any interest in the autogenerated playlist following that video. Is there a way to disable the mix recommendations entirely, or at least replace them with recommendations for just the original seed video without the autogenerated playlist feature?